# Specific flag for warning 'ordered comparison between pointer and zero'

Tags: objective-c, clang, clang-static-analyzer

This code has a pointer int comparison I want to catch as an error:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
BOOL test = (number > 0); //should have a warning
```

The only flag I've found that will catch this is the very broad `-Wpedantic`

```
error: ordered comparison between pointer and zero ('NSDecimalNumber *' and 'int') is an extension [-Werror,-Wpedantic]
BOOL test = (number > 0);
             ~~~~~~ ^ ~
```

Is there a more specific warning flag to catch this operation as an error/warning?